# Why my SetHint in xamarin android does not work?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I set the hint programmatically for a purpose `edittext.SetHint("MyHint");` but it does not work.

```
namespace MhylesApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "ToExistingCustomer"/*, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape*/)]
    public class ToExistingCustomer : Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity
    {
        private EditText edittext;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ExistingCustomer);
            edittext= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.qty);
            edittext.SetHint("My Hint");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work? are you sure about the color? (I mean make sure you using different colors for hint color and edit text background color), also make sure you found correct element. (_`FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.qty)`_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetHint() method takes a resource as an argument. Instead of hard-coding a string, go to Resources> Values> strings.xml and add:

```
<string name="my_hint">My Hint</string>
```

Then in your code, set

```
edittext.SetHint(Resource.String.my_hint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Mono.Droid` its always good to remember that it is .Net based and to make it easier for .Net developers and to follow the .Net coding standards the get and set type methods are actually properties in Xamarin so your hint should be set like this:

```
  edittext.Hint = "Your text";
```

Goodluck

Feel free to revert if you have queries